# How to know where wget store it's data and which process started it

Tags: 14.04, networking, wget

I have noticed that I download slower than I did days ago. So used NetHogs to monitor which process that use my bandwidth. I saw that there's wget process that I didn't launched that it's consuming all my bandwidth. I killed the process but it's launched again. How can I know which process started it. Or can I know where it downloads the data?

NetHogs show that there's 2 wget process (that what I have started), another wget process, python, firefox and this line

```
?    root    unknown TCP        0.000     0.000 KB/sec
```

When I do top : I see that boinc is consuming almost all CPUs, I don't see strange process.

Comment: Can you post more data? The NetHogs report? Your version of ubuntu? A `ps aux` or a `top`?

Comment: Now I killed it doesn't restarted yet, how to NetHogs report? Or you want just what it print to the screen?

Comment: i don't know but maybe boinc downloads something

Comment: what is wget ppid? it's the same as boinc pid?

Comment: When I have did ps aux it appears that the other wget process is the one I have canceled. But I don't how it restarted!

Comment: can you look /proc/<pid> folder? There is more information about process. details: http://serverfault.com/a/233250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ps axjf` shows which process started it. Also this will show its pid, process id. 
Then use `ls -l /proc/4043/cwd` replacing 4043 with PID you are interesting it, this will show what is current directory of that wget. This is most likely place for saving downloaded data. 
Otherwise examine what parameters were passed to that wget by `cat /proc/4043/cmdline` (again, your PID instead of 4043).